# Proving equation with Poisson summation formula?

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm trying to use the fact that:

$$\sum_{n = -\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(\tau + n)^2} = (-2\pi i)^2\sum_{m = 1}^{\infty}me^{2\pi i m\tau}$$

for a fixed $\tau$ with $Im(\tau) > 0$ to show that if $Im(\tau) > 0$, then:

$$\sum_{n = -\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(\tau + n)^2} = \frac{\pi^2}{\sin^2({\pi \tau})}$$

I figure I'm supposed to use the Poisson summation formula, but am very stuck as to how to proceed...

Thanks!

Comment: How did you proved the first fact?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

But you already wrote the whole thing...almost!:

$$\sum_{n\in\Bbb Z}\frac1{(\tau+n)^2}=(-2\pi i)^2\sum_{m=1}^\infty me^{2\pi im\tau}$$

But we have that

$$|z|<1\implies\sum_{n=0}^\infty z^n=\frac1{1-z}\implies\sum_{n=1}^\infty nz^n=z\left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty z^n\right)'=\frac z{(1-z)^2}$$

and since

$$\left|e^{2\pi i\tau}\right|=\left|e^{2\pi i(\text{Re}\,\tau+i\,\text{Im}\,\tau )}\right|=\left|\,e^{-2\pi \,\text{Im}\,\tau+2\pi i\,\text{Re}\,\tau}\,\right|=e^{-2\pi \,\text{Im}\,\tau}<1$$

we get

$$=(-2\pi i)^2\sum_{m=1}^\infty me^{2\pi im\tau}=-4\pi^2\frac{e^{2\pi i\tau}}{\left(1-e^{2\pi i\tau}\right)^2}$$

Now just remember that

$$\sin\pi\tau=\frac{e^{i\pi\tau}-e^{-i\pi\tau}}{2i}=\frac{e^{2\pi i\tau}-1}{2ie^{\pi i\tau}}$$

Comment: Thanks -- everything makes sense except the seemingly simple conclusion that you draw from the geometric series:

$$|z|<1\implies\sum_{n=0}^\infty z^n=\frac1{1-z}\implies\sum_{n=1}^\infty nz^n=z\left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty z^n\right)'=\frac z{(1-z)^2}$$

Can you expand a little about how the summation from $n = 1$ to $\infty$ is derived? Thanks.

Comment: Well, if you write that from $\;n=0\;$ the first summand is zero, so it is boring...All the rest is power series stuff: we can differentiate/integrate elementwise a power series within its interval of convergence, and that's what was done above.